# Interactive Notification issue - automatically clears all notification while action on single notification

Tags: objective-c, ios8, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, interactive

I have implemented interactive notification using two actions. When app is not running, and i get 4-5 notifications on lock screen, then if I submit any one action, it clears all notifications automatically, this should not be done. I have just called one webservice on that action. Not clearing all notifications manually, still having same issue.

Video Link https://www.dropbox.com/s/fszdsgnrn7rfb2h/Voicee_issue.MOV?dl=0

You can find my code here :
https://www.dropbox.com/s/5gp5tzcryhlwtyk/appdelegate.rtf?dl=0

Comment: Post your relevant codes as well in question body...

Comment: @Aditya 

Video Link of issue https://www.dropbox.com/s/fszdsgnrn7rfb2h/Voicee_issue.MOV?dl=0

You can find my code here : https://www.dropbox.com/s/5gp5tzcryhlwtyk/appdelegate.rtf?dl=0

Comment: solved. I have implemented background mode- remote notification & - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler{} method at appdelegate.